# Symfony2 passing to constructor doctrine entity manager throwing error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

On each of my  controllers,   i need to  run  security enforcing  function from constructor. Problem is that i cannot  run doctrine entity manager in constructor to load user id from session,  and call findby function from on my user  entity. 
Only way  i found  is to call  this security enforcing function on each of  my actions,  which is not optimal - code not clean, and alot of function calls. 
I have searched and test many of  user solutions from  stackoverflow - many of them is copy  paste of others not working code. 
My services.yml file:

```
services:
    app.default_controller:
        class: AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController
        arguments:
            - @doctrine.orm.entity_manager
```

My  DefaultController class (its sample controller):

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    protected $em;
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        // replace this example code with whatever you need
        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', array(
            'base_dir' => realpath($this->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/..'),
        ));
    }

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em = null){
        $this->em=$em;

      $personRepository = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AppBundle\Entity\Person');
        //$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    }
}
```

I always having doctrine errors whatever i not do with  constructor.
[Often error example, when im trying to access website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2AYn.png)

PS. I'm using Symfony 2.8.2, this code examples are not from actual app

Answer (score 0):

please allow me to suggest a different approach. You're better using symfony event system :)

You can set up listeners to be executed before and after any action of your controller.

Just tag the events you want to subscribe to and dispatch them o a service you create for security purposes.

Checkout symfony documentation regarding this [How to Set Up Before and After Filters](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html)

Good luck! :)